# How to get url path in angular2 dart

Tags: angular, dart, angular2-routing, angular-dart

I'm calling an URL like "123.123.123.123/client/12345" and would like to use a client-component to show the client with the id 12345 in my root component.

At the moment i'm using the Route class as follows:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
    const Route(path: '/:link/:id', name: 'start', component:RootComponent)])
```

and in RootComponent implements OnInit I have

```
final _routeParams;

RootComponent(this._routeParams);
Client client;

ngOnInit() async {
    var link = _routeParams.get('link');
    if (link=="client") {
          client = GetClientById(_routeParams.get("id"));
    }
 }
```

This isn't working. It's failing with the message "No provider for RouteParams!"

Does anybody know how to get the components of the URL in angular2, or should I just use standard dart url parsing?

Comment: You need to add a type annotation `final RouteParams _routeParams;` for this to work but from the error message I think you did. I think you need to add more information to your question for others to be able to diagnose the problem. I don't understand how you want to derive the component from the `RouteParams`.

Comment: What is the difference between `RootComponent` and `RouteComponent` Do you also have an `AppComponent`?

Comment: You can try to inject `Location` and get `location.path()`. Not sure though what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I was just trying to put some of the application in another view or component. I'll have a look at injecting location.

Comment: "I was just trying to put some of the application in another view or component." Isn't that what the router does?

Comment: yes, it's what i'd like to do, but i can't find a way to access the current browser location in angular2. I'm now getting the error "No provider for LocationStrategy!". I'll update my code ... EDIT create a new post

Comment: Seems your project setup is missing some essential parts. Please post more code. I still don't understand what you try to accomplish exactly. The router should do what you want without you accessing the URL directly. Just configure the router, routes and router-outlets properly.

Comment: thank you for your help :) My problem with using the router is that other components need access to the client object, so i'd like to fetch it in the main app_component, so I can pass it to the various components which need it.

Comment: What is a client object? What don't you just provide it as service and inject it where needed?

Comment: I need to read the URL to know which client object to provide. As it is, i'm reaching the child object using [client]="client" in the .html file, which i don't think is very type-safe. I'll look into supplying it as a service.